# Spring-boot 2.0.0 enable auditJPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a sample project for audit JPA. I'm trying to migrate this project to spring-boot 2.0.0.RELEASE so I get an unload class exception for a aop class, the project address:
https://github.com/richardcsantana/spring-audit-sample/tree/spring-boot-2.0.0

The pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.richardcsantana</groupId>
<artifactId>auditsample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>audit-sample</name>
<description>Demo project using audit from spring-jpa</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory
                    of the image -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                <registryUrl>https://hub.docker.com/</registryUrl>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

When I run the tests or try to run the app, it was giving the following error:

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException**

with the stack:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>               at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>               at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:179)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               ... 28 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect]
>   from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6bc7c054]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:599)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:728)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:669)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:637)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1007)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:168)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:157)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:207)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:114)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:266)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:255)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:197)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>               ... 44 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/NoAspectBoundException
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>               at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>               at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>               ... 61 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>               at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>               ... 65 common frames omitted

With this test class:

```
package com.richardcsantana;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AuditSampleApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This exceptions happens on JUnit Test execution. Can you provide the source code of the unittest?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli here the code, it's a simple spring placeholder test

`package com.richardcsantana;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AuditSampleApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}`